# What is the proper way to use add_rewrite_rule to remove the (question mark)?

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I have a page called "People" with a custom template that takes in a variable called name:

example.com/people/?name=FirstLast

What I want is this:

example.com/people/FristLast

I know I need to use the add_rewrite_rule and add_rewrite_tag calls but I'm not sure how to achieve my desired result. I've tried this but I get a php error:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^people/([^/]*)/?','index.php?name=$matches[1]','top');
add_rewrite_tag('%name%','([^&]+)');
```

The error I get is: "Fatal error: Call to a member function add_rule() on a non-object"

I think I'm on the right path. I'm very knowledgeable with WP but this is my first attempt to the rewrite rule.

Thanks!

----- EDIT -----
I've updated the code. I no longer get an error but nothing "happens"

```
function rewrite_rule_people() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_tag('%name%','([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^people/([^/]*)','index.php?page_id=42602&name=$matches[1]','top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_rule_people' );
```

going to /people/?name=JohnSmith doesn't change the url to /people/JohnSmith

Comment: Be careful about using `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules()` as it's pretty hefty, programmatically speaking.  You can achieve the same effect by going to Settings->Permalinks in the admin screens and saving your Permalink settings.  See http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your page id of "People" page. If i assume it is 12 then this will do,

```
add_rewrite_rule('^people/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12&name=$matches[1]','top');
```

Comment: added the page id (and some additional code). Now I'm no longer getting an error but the url doesn't respond to the rewrite. (see edit)

Comment: @dcp3450 Try adding "/?" at end of rewrite rule

Comment: @dcp3450 you no longer need to go to "people?name=xxx", after adding rewrite rule, you have to use new url "people/JohnSmith"

Comment: adding the "/?" worked. thanks!

Comment: Adding `/?` to the end simply makes the trailing slash in the request an optional part of the URL, ie. `people/SomePerson` and `people/SomePerson/` are both valid, without the trailing slash only the former is accounted for. Stated for anyone curious to know what that part of the code does.